# Styling Custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I've created something similar to a listview via a xml file containing an ImageView and TextView and using the LayoutInflater.

It seems I've done this in quite an unorthodox way, as I can't figure out how to actually style the listview (ideally I want to define the size as there's other content to be put on the same interface)

I've tried styling the LinearLayout inself, and putting the LinearLayout within a parent LinearLayout, including a ListView within the said file named 'list', trying to define a setContentView within the class which extends ListActivity.

I would love just to be able to include the custom listview control into a LinearLayout just like any other control, rather than the control being the entire UI.

```
public class ImageActivity extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceStore> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<PlaceStore> places;

    public ImageActivity(Context context, List<PlaceStore> places) {
        super(context, R.layout.image_text_row, places);
        this.context = context;
        this.places = places;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_text_row, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        textView.setText(places.get(position).getName());

        return rowView;
    }


public class FavouriteActivity extends ListActivity{


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.favourite);

         FavouriteData data = new FavouriteData(this);

         List<PlaceStore> pS = data.returnFileData();

         setListAdapter(new ImageActivity(this, pS));

    }
```

R.layout.image_text_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" android:background="@drawable/background_type" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/androidmarker" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can put the list view inside a linear layout. Then load its items into an adapter, and set the adapter to the list view. If you have time, consider watching this video: [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70).